# Increase deadline timeout for Google PubSub

Tags: c#, .net, google-cloud-pubsub

We're intermittently getting the following errors when publishing messages to Google PubSub topics when using the C# libraries:

```
Exception: Grpc.Core.RpcException: Status(StatusCode=Unauthenticated, Detail="Deadline Exceeded")
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ApiCallRetryExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass0_0`2.<<WithRetry>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1.Tasks.ForwardingAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1.Tasks.Extensions.<>c__DisplayClass6_0`1.<<ConfigureAwaitHideErrors>g__Inner0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1.Tasks.ForwardingAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1.SimplePublisherImpl.<PublishAsync>d__26.MoveNext()
   at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ApiCallRetryExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass0_0`2.<<WithRetry>b__0>d.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

Which Google tells me is a configurable timeout. We're configuring the client libraries like so:

```
private SimplePublisher CreateSimplePublisher(int maxItems, int maxSizeBytes, TimeSpan maxDelay)
{
    var credential = Credential.IsCreateScopedRequired ?
        Credential.CreateScoped(PublisherClient.DefaultScopes) : Credential;
    var channel = new Channel(
        PublisherClient.DefaultEndpoint.Host,
        PublisherClient.DefaultEndpoint.Port,
        credential.ToChannelCredentials());
    var publisherClient = PublisherClient.Create(channel);
    return SimplePublisher.Create(
        new TopicName(Project, Topic),
        new[] { publisherClient },
        new SimplePublisher.Settings
        {
            BatchingSettings = new BatchingSettings
            (
                elementCountThreshold: maxItems,
                byteCountThreshold: maxSizeBytes,
                delayThreshold: maxDelay
            )
        });
}
```

Does anyone know how to configure the deadline threshold in this configuration? This is using version `1.0.0-beta13`of the `Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1` client libraries nuget package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be controlled by passing a `PublisherSettings` object to the `PublisherClient.Create` call.

```
private SimplePublisher CreateSimplePublisher(int maxItems, int maxSizeBytes, TimeSpan maxDelay)
{
    var credential = Credential.IsCreateScopedRequired ?
        Credential.CreateScoped(PublisherClient.DefaultScopes) : Credential;
    var channel = new Channel(
        PublisherClient.DefaultEndpoint.Host,
        PublisherClient.DefaultEndpoint.Port,
        credential.ToChannelCredentials());
    //Add a specific timeout for the publish operation
    var publisherClientSettings = new PublisherSettings
    {
        PublishSettings = CallSettings.FromCallTiming(CallTiming.FromTimeout(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60)))
    };
    var publisherClient = PublisherClient.Create(channel,publisherClientSettings);
    return SimplePublisher.Create(
        new TopicName(Project, Topic),
        new[] { publisherClient },
        new SimplePublisher.Settings
        {
            BatchingSettings = new BatchingSettings
            (
                elementCountThreshold: maxItems,
                byteCountThreshold: maxSizeBytes,
                delayThreshold: maxDelay
            )
        });
}
```

Comment: Is there an updated answer given the changes from 1.0.0-beta15 to 1.0.0-beta16: "PublisherSettings is now named PublisherServiceApiSettings" ?